# Issues with batch write to txt

Tags: date, batch-file, logging

I am working on a fancy Zip archive cracker and its working perfectly.
And I successfully made it write the output to a log file. however my problem is:
if I run a crack on the same file again just couple of seconds later, it will overwrite the already existing log, but what I want to do is:
if the log file already exist. it will not overwrite the log file. but it will ADD in the new output of the new crack to the already existing file so when I open the log I will then see both of the cracks that I have done in same log file.

heres the code:

```
    (
echo ==============================================
echo                  Crack log
echo ==============================================
echo.
echo PASSWORD FOUND!
echo Date/time log for decryption: %Date%\%time%
echo FILE  = %NAME%
echo CRACKED PASSWORD = %PSWD%
echo Tests: %PSWD1%
echo.
echo Time Spendt to crack Archive: %hh%:%mm%:%ss%,%cc%
echo Hours: %hh%
echo Minutes: %mm%
echo Seconds: %ss%
echo Centisecods: %cc%


) > %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt
    if exist %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt >> %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt
```

ok this problem has now been solved by:
@Aacini and @mofi 
Solution: Change ) > %Date%*Cracklog*%NAME%.txt by ) >> %Date%*Cracklog*%NAME%.txt and delete the next line

==========================================================================

however now I got another problem.
i managed to add in on bottom line a function that creates a directory for each crack log. wich looks like this:

"MKDIR Logs\%name%
) >> %Date%*Cracklog*%NAME%.txt"

the mkdir works perfectly. the point with it is creating a subdirectory under the logs folder with the name of the cracked zip archive.
and the problem that is still there is that I got no idea how to make the script to create the  actual log file inside that directory,

ive been googling and testing several things but I find nothing that really works. and at the same time. if I decide to crack another file, well yeh then the scripts makes a new sub directory but then  I also want the new log file into its belonging folder.

anyone got any idea how to fix that?

(thanks for all help so far<3 I love ya guys)
if you choose to help  me futher. please write an example or a helping answere  by clicking the answere question button so i can give you reputation :D)

==============================================================================
Edit:
Managed to find out the last problem myself, I just took a break from all thinking then went back with a cup of coffee and then voila solution popped up in my head... I guess I was just a bit tired. however this is how I solved the problem:

```
(
echo ==============================================
echo                  Crack log
echo ==============================================
echo.
echo PASSWORD FOUND!
echo Date/time log for decryption: %Date%\%time%
echo FILE  = %NAME%
echo CRACKED PASSWORD = %PSWD%
echo Tests: %PSWD1%
echo.
echo Time Spendt to crack Archive: %hh%:%mm%:%ss%,%cc%
echo Hours: %hh%
echo Minutes: %mm%
echo Seconds: %ss%
echo Centisecods: %cc%
MKDIR Logs\%name%
) >> Logs\%name%\%Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt
```

Comment: See [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). Your batch file must end with `) >> %Date%Cracklog%NAME%.txt`, i.e. `>>` instead of `>`. Environment variable __DATE__ has just the date string and not time string. And in English US the date string is `mm/dd/yyyy` with `/` not being a valid character in a file name.

Comment: delete the very last line. It's just nonsense, leading to a Syntax error

Comment: the line " > %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt" is working perfectly. and date is also workign perfectly. this line creates the txt as it should but the line im troubling with is " if exist %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt >> %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt"    so in order to fix this as i understood it i may do     ) > %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt
 )   if exist %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt >> %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt "?

Comment: Change `) > %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt` by `) >> %Date%_Cracklog_%NAME%.txt` and delete the next line

Comment: OHHH nvm i misunderstood your answere. i got it right now. i thought i had to use > in order to create and write the txt then if i wanted more info i needed to use >> xD but that was wrong. im sorry but im still very new to this and im still learning :P  however. i found out making the txt file save to same directory is a pain in the ass.... anyone got any ideas of how to make the script create a sub directory for each "new" crack then put the txt file in there?